# How to prevent location change of all components after update of nodeDataArray of diagram?

Tags: javascript, gojs

I have this diagram:

```
var $ = go.GraphObject.make;
var diagram = $(go.Diagram, element[0], {
     initialContentAlignment: go.Spot.TopCenter,
     initialScale: 1,
     layout: $(go.LayeredDigraphLayout, { direction: 0 }),
     isReadOnly: false,
     allowLink: true,
     allowClipboard: false,
     animationManager.duration: 200,
     undoManager.isEnabled: false
});
```

I create several simple elements and add them using **addNodeDataCollection** method to diagram model. Then I change the position of elements and add one more to *nodeDataArray*. I expect that after adding of new element the position of old items won't be changed but this is not true. The locations of all items are changed and all elements are aligned by center. Is it a correct behaviour? I didn't find how to prevent recalculation of locations after adding new item in *nodeDataArray*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally when you add or remove a node or a link, the layout will be performed again. In this case your **Diagram.layout** will happen again, moving back the manually adjusted node positions to where the layout thinks they should be. Please read http://gojs.net/latest/intro/layouts.html for more details, especially the section about "Layout Invalidation".

In your case I'm not sure what you really want to accomplish. It might be sufficient to set **Layout.isOngoing** to false on your **LayeredDigraphLayout** instance.

Comment: Great. Layout.isOngoing is what I searched. Thanks!